# Would like to clone a dual boot system (windows and ubuntu) from two different drives to one bigger different drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot system with windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04 on the first and second nvme ssd respectively. I bought a bigger nvme ssd and would like to clone both systems together onto the same new drive. what do I do best?

So far I cloned windows to the new drive and created a new ext4 partition with the remaining free space but I am unsure how to clone the ubuntu system to this partition in one run. Should I use clonezilla and create an image file in the location of the ext4 partition on the new drive and then later restore from there?

I haven't found a way to clone a complete drive to one specific partition on another drive yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were both installs UEFI with gpt partitioning? You have to be careful not to create duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs, if still booting when old drives are installed. I suggest new install & restore from your backup. Proves backup is complete, so later if drive fails you know you can easily restore it. And still have old drive to restore anything you missed in backup. You can rsync data, but new UUIDs, will require reinstall of grub, so new ESP is recognized in ESP & fstab.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't know anymore to be honest, but  UEFI with gpt partitioning rings a bell. Will back up ubuntu now und will go first with a reinstall of ubuntu on the new disk, thank you!